# Creating Virtual Directory on IIS for Coldfusion Lucee

Tags: iis, coldfusion, lucee

I am trying to Move my Website on a local directory from Adobe Coldfusion to Lucee.
I was able to Install Lucee with the Windows Installer.
IIS is working fine.

When i Create a Virtual Directory from IIS to Map a Physical Path (C:/Website) outside the inetpub root folder (FOR IIS) or outside the Tomcat/webapps/ROOT folder (for Lucee), IIS doesn't load that physical folder. Instead it loads the inetpub root folder and i can't access files from the Physical Path Directory.

I am using //localhost/{The Alias} to call the Website but saying file not not found.
Obviously because it's calling from Inetpub file Directory, not the Physical path.

Are there any special configurations i need to make?

I have searched online and no post could help.

Note that i am using different computers.

Kindly Assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mod_cfml (the adapter that is used with Lucee/IIS along with the BonCode Connector) does not currently support virtual directories. You will need to configure those manually in the Tomcat context config, like so:

```
<Host name="lucee.org" appBase="/home/lucee/public_html">
 <Context path="/vdir/" docBase="/home/other_user/public_html/some_other_directory/" />
 <Alias>www.lucee.org</Alias>
</Host>
```

Comment: Tomcat is pretty well documented. Host: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/host.html, Context: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html. I'd recommend creating the IIS virtual directory first, then create the tomcat context.